# QuickEditIntegration can't process components for Quick Edit

Tags: 9, layout-builder

I have a content type that is displayed with Layout Builder. When I view it in default mode, the Quick Edit option does not appear in the contextual menu. This is because none of the fields have the `data-quickedit-field-id` attribute.

I spent a couple of days chasing this down. Apparently the issue comes up in this function in `core/modules/layout_builder/src/QuickEditIntegration.php`.

```
  private function supportQuickEditOnComponent(array $component, FieldableEntityInterface $entity) {
    if (isset($component['content']['#field_name'], $component['#base_plugin_id']) && $component['#base_plugin_id'] === 'field_block' && $entity->hasField($component['content']['#field_name'])) {
      return $entity->getFieldDefinition($component['content']['#field_name'])->isDisplayConfigurable('view');
    }
    return FALSE;
  }
```

When `entityViewAlter` calls `supportQuickEditOnComponent`, the $component array contains an unexpected nested array...

[image: snapshot of JSON structure]

and all the stuff that's supposed to be inside `content` is instead nested in a subarray `[0]`. As a result of that, the function returns `false` and none of the fields get added to `$plugin_ids_to_update` and thus they are not parsed inside this loop in `entityViewAlter`:

```
  foreach ($plugin_ids_to_update as $delta => $regions) {
    foreach ($regions as $region => $uuids) {
      foreach ($uuids as $uuid => $component) {
        $build['_layout_builder'][$delta][$region][$uuid]['content']['#view_mode'] = static::getViewModeId($entity, $display, $delta, $uuid, $sections_hash);
      }
    }
  }
```

... which is where the view mode ID is assigned that enables that `data-quickedit-field-id` attribute to be added by Quick Edit later.

I've "fixed" this by hacking `QuickEditIntegration.php` in two places, collapsing the subarray `[0]` into the main `$component` array. I know this is not the right way to do it. What could be causing these Layout Builder components to be populated into a subarray instead of where QuickEditIntegration is expecting to find them?